# Adding extjs4 application to codeigniter application

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, extjs, codeigniter-2, extjs4.2

So I have a basic CodeIgniter application and a basic ExtJs 4 application:

I want my ExtJs 4 application to be served up as one of the pages of my codeigniter application.

I tried dumping my whole extjs4 project inside of the root directory under assets/extjs_app/. I then took the index.html from the extjs4 project and made it a template file (index.php) called by one of my controller actions.

Now I am new with both of these technologies and as of yet have not had to include any js / css into my codeigniter application. I have

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Account Manager</title>
    <!-- <x-compile> -->
        <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
            <script src="<?= base_url('assets/extjs_app') ?>/ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
            <script src="<?= base_url('assets/extjs_app') ?>/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="<?= base_url('assets/extjs_app') ?>/app.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-compile> -->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

It isn't picking up the js or css files though.

What am i missing? Also, this is just a hack job on my part. Is there any documentation of combining these two technologies elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is that ALL of my requests were getting forwarded to my front controller due to rewrite rules in my top-level .htaccess.

I added:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets)
```

to the htaccess file and am now able to access the application resources. I am going to try to put together a better file system. Something like https://github.com/richie87/codeigniter-meets-extjs possibly.

Hope this helps someone else.